# Error MSB4064: The "NETCoreSdkRuntimeIdentifier" parameter is not supported by the "PrepareForReadyToRunCompilation" when use PostSharp

Tags: c#, postsharp, .net-standard-2.0

I am trying to compile a solution with a .netstandard 2.0 projects in vs 2019(v16.10)
and I got this error message (I use PostSharp):

> Error MSB4064 The "NETCoreSdkRuntimeIdentifier" parameter is not supported by the "PrepareForReadyToRunCompilation" task loaded from assembly: Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks, Version=5.0.4.26711, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 from the path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\tools\net5.0\Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.dll. Verify that the parameter exists on the task, the  points to the correct assembly, and it is a settable public instance property.    PROJECT.ASSEMBLY.NAME C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\CrossGenPaths\sdk5.0.300-netcoreapp5.0-r5.0.6-win-x64\CrossGen.proj

Anyone know about this?

Comment: This is probably an incompatibility with the new SDK, as a workaround, you can disable PostSharp's attempts to create r2r images by setting PostSharpReadyToRunDisabled MSBuild property to True (or you can set an env var of the same name).

Comment: It's work, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the  [@Daniel Balas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622389/daniel-balas)'s answer, I added this to the .csproj file:
`<PostSharpReadyToRunDisabled>True</PostSharpReadyToRunDisabled>`

It works!
Thanks!